# Aircraft simulation

Tags: physics, javascript, projectile-physics, three.js

Trying to get a "semi" realistic aircraft simulator. I'm pulling my hair out because I just can't get the math right. I'm not looking for super realistic but want to at least get some effects like planes increasing speed as their nose is down and being able to stay in flight.

Pseudocode below from my `calculateForces` method

```
// All uses of X are different constants


force = new Vector(0,0,0)

airPlaneYaw = plane.rotation.x;
airPlanePitch = plane.rotation.y;
airPlaneRoll = plane.rotation.z;

velocityDirection = plane.velocity.normalize();
airPlaneNoseDirection = plane.getWorldDirection();
airPlaneSurfaceAgainstDirectionOfMotion = airPlaneNoseDirection.angleTo(velocityDirection)
airPlaneSpeed = plane.velocity.length();

drag = X*(speed**2) * sin(airPlaneSurfaceAgainstDirectionOfMotion); // I have a feeling this is wrong

thrust = X;

lift = X * (speed**2) * sin(airPlaneYaw); // I have a feeling this is wrong?

gravity = X;

force.add(velocityDirection.multiply(drag));
force.add(airPlaneNoseDirection.multiply(thrust);
force.add(Vector(0,lift,0);
force.add(Vector(0,gravity,0);

velocity.add(force);
```

Is this the right model for approaching this? Is my math incorrect? Am I missing any forces?

My plane seems to lose speed when turning even if thrust is constant and ends up falling down. Is that expected in real life? Very annoying in my game because the plane becomes harder to control. Do planes add thrust when turning? Also the plane seems to gain airspeed when nose is down.

Comment: And, I think lift force should't be vertical. If so you will not get planes increasing speed as their nose is down. See [LiftForce](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(force)).

Comment: @Mangata that would be accurate if we knew that this question was in the context of the Unity game engine and that `plane` refers to a `Transform` component, but we can readily see that's not the case: `Transform` does not have a `.velocity` property or field or a `.getWorldDirection()` method. For K2xL: it would help to mention the context and coordinate system you're building this in, and how the behaviour of this code differs from what you want.

Comment: Working with threejs if that context helps.  Will edit question with more details of behavior

Comment: @Mangata How should lift force be applied? Should it be angle of the aircraft or should it be something else? For reference, i found this from NASA which I interpreted lift as a vertical force https://wright.nasa.gov/airplane/lifteq.html

Comment: A fluid flowing around an object exerts a force on it. Lift is the component of this force that is perpendicular to the oncoming flow direction. [Lift_(force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(force))

Comment: @Mangata so should I have it apply to the vector perpendicular to the airplane orientation or motion direction?

Comment: basically yes. but airplane orientation is not always equal to the direction of motion. See [Angle_of_attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack). :)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Mangata, but I'm still a bit confused. So I get the vector between the direction of the aircraft and the direction of motion and call that AngleOfAttack - but I imagine that with constant thrust those two angles will converge right?

Comment: Generally AOA is controllable to a certain extent, through wing control. AOA and the (jet?) engine together determine the movement trend of the airplane. with constant thrust, there needs to be a specific AOA to keep the plane moving in a straight line at a constant speed.

Comment: Thanks @Mangata. Unfortunately, I have been pulling my hair out all day trying different things. I made a table with the CL and CD coefficients. However, now i am super confused on how to get the direction of lift.